# csquotes option thresholdtype=words gives error

Tags: csquotes

A student of mine recently had a question concerning the `\blockquote` command of the `csquotes` package.

He asked, why some blockquotes had quotes, while others didn't.  Regarding the manual, I planned to advise him, to use the `threshold` and `thresholdtype` options, to define the limits, to present the quote as block instead of inline.

So I set up this MWE for him:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, oneside, parskip=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[autostyle=true, german]{csquotes}
%% This gives an error!
\usepackage[autostyle=true, german, threshold=2, thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
%% Same here!
% \ExecuteQuoteOptions{thresholdtype=words}
%% This works as expected!
% \ExecuteQuoteOptions{thresholdtype=lines}

\begin{document}

%% This works:
\blockquote{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Wiederholte Einwirkungen
  \item Impulse mit längerer Einwirkungsdauer, z.\,B.\ Fußauftritte
  \item Impulse mit kürzerer Einwirkungsdauer.
  \end{enumerate}
}

%% ... while this gives an error, but only, if the option thresholdtype=words is used!
\blockquote{7.3.3 Wohnungsdecken
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Wiederholte Einwirkungen
  \item Impulse mit längerer Einwirkungsdauer, z.\,B.\ Fußauftritte
  \item Impulse mit kürzerer Einwirkungsdauer.
  \end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

But instead of a solution I got errors, that a item should be missing.  If you use `thresholdtype=lines` (the other possible value), the error message disappears.

Any idea what went wrong?  `csqotes` package is of version v5.2l.

Comment: It seems like a bug in how the word counting code processes (list) environments. If you use `debug=true` as package option with the `words` threshold then before the error message for the second block the debug info for the first block is printed as `Package csquotes Debug: \blockquote has 1 words. Threshold is 2.` which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: I filed a bug-report: https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/57

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report and off topic ...